# Access to connections denied

Tags: linkedin-api, hybridauth

Anyone is having problems retrieving Likendin connections with new apps?
With old apps my hybridauth app is retrieving connections just fine. While with new apps (I created 3 different apps) I keep getting **Access to connections denied**

When authenticating I got the correct scopes on likedin login screen(r_basic_profile, r_network, w_messages, r_emailaddresses)

Im using free plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-social-invitations/ which uses hybridauth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linkedin api changed recently, that's the reason scopes are not longer working

Comment: Hi @chifliiii 
How we can fetch the connection now ?

Comment: You can't you need a partner account

Answer (score 6):

This is a recent problem with the linked. They have stopped providing member connection in their recent API change. Now you have to obtain a partner certificate in order to access member connection information. Even my production application has stopped this functionality to work. We might be removing linked from our application as it is of no use now with so much of restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The get connections API in linked in has been deprecated follow this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) to get the API' that are allowed as part of developers program right now.